# react change the contents of state

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to change the query part of name, age, country of data of state.
... {data: {... state.data, [key] .query: e.target.value}}, but at [key] .query, Parsing error:':' expected.eslint It will end up.
How should I fix it?
If anyone knows, please let me know.

```
interface Data {
  name?: Name;
  age?: Age;
  country?: Country;
}

interface Name {
  query: string;
  current: boolean;
}

interface Age {
  query: string;
  current: boolean;
}

interface Country {
  query: string;
  current: boolean;
}

const initial: Name | Age | Country = {
  query: '',
  current: false,
};

const initialdata: Data = {
  name: initial,
  age: initial,
  country: initial,
}

interface State {
  data: Data;
  text: string;
  modal: boolean
}

const Index: FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
    data: initialdata,
    text: '',
    modal: false,
  });


  // Where to call this function, one of Data's name, age, country is passed like onChangeWithKey (ChangeEvent <HTMLInputElement>,'name').
  const onChangeWithKey = (e: any, key: string) => {
    setState({ ...state, ...{data: { ...state.data, [key].query: e.target.value } } });
  };
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear. maybe share some more code example of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

`[key].query` isn't a valid object key. Also, make sure you maintain the `state.data` property.

```
const onChangeWithKey = (e: any, key: string) => {
  setState({
    ...state, // <-- copy state
    data: {
      ...state.data, // <-- copy state.data
      [key]: { // <-- update specific key property
        ...state.data[key], // <-- copy state.data[key]
        query: e.target.value // <-- update query property
      },
    } ,
  });
};
```

Comment: thankyou. 
Implemented by the above method.
However, if name is passed as an argument, age and current other than name will disappear.

Comment: ideal   name: {query: "aaaaaaaa", current: false} age: {query: "", current: false} country: {query: "", current: false}

Comment: @TOYUU Did you copy `state.data`? `state.data` has the `name`, `age` and `country` properties. You ***must*** copy state at each level you intend to update.

Comment: The above process　　name: {query: "aaaaaa", current: false}

Comment: I implemented the above process as it is